# Web Config Transforms are HTML Encoding some of the config and breaking it

Tags: web-config, msdeploy, xdt-transform, publish-profiles, web.config-transform

I have the following:

`Web.Config` (this is a segment of an NLog configuration)

```
<target name="fileAsException" 
        xsi:type="FilteringWrapper" 
        condition="length('${exception}')>0">
    ... removed ...
</target>
```

This is translated to the following when built with release:

```
<target name="fileAsException" 
        xsi:type="FilteringWrapper" 
        condition="length('${exception}')&gt;0">
    ... removed ...
</target>
```

As you can see the `condition` expression has been HTML Encoded resulting in the `&gt;` replacing the `>`.  This causes the condition to not work.

There is nothing specific to this within my `web.release.config` file, it is simply copied over from the base `web.config`.

How can I suppress this encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have spoken to Microsoft and they have asked me to open a bug.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/797554/web-config-transforms-are-html-encoding-some-of-the-config-and-breaking-it