# Stop ">" symbol from being converted to "&gt;" in web.config transform

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment, web-config, escaping

When I run my Web.config transforms, it converts the **`>`** symbol to **`&gt;`**. Is there a way to escape this conversion?

input:

```
<add key="MyPassword" value=">" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
```

undesired output:

```
<add key="MyPassword" value="&gt;" />
```

desired output:

```
<add key="MyPassword" value=">" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like this is expected behavior.  In this related question you can see the user submitted a bug to Microsoft, which they have closed as "By Design".

[Web Config Transforms are HTML Encoding some of the config and breaking it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225737/web-config-transforms-are-html-encoding-some-of-the-config-and-breaking-it)

Answer (score 0):

The Nature of XML prevents this.

In an effort to not leave you hanging here are some suggestions.

1. google CDATA in Web.config,
2. You may wish to create a method that 1. Reads the setting and 2. Decodes the value.
3. With that being said, the nature of XML read and writes, this value should be returned unencoded. I see you are working with MVC. Just as a pointer perhaps this is working as intended and you simply need to @Html.Raw() your output in your view? Just a guess.

Good luck.